# Prevent direct call of a file

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, files

I'm not even sure if this is possible; I'm on an apache server. For the file located at:

```
http://www.example.com/dir/img.jpg
```

- Allow this image to be loaded in a page called from that directory.
- Disallow this image to be loaded directly; ie. the url above should not load
- Prevent linking this image from a page located elsewhere

The purpose is the file should only be able to be displayed on the particular page its destined for; it should not be viewable directly. Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html#blocked-inline-images):

> Blocked Inline-Images
>
> Description:   Assume we have under
>   http://www.quux-corp.de/~quux/ some
>   pages with inlined GIF graphics. These
>   graphics are nice, so others directly
>   incorporate them via hyperlinks to
>   their pages. We don't like this
>   practice because it adds useless
>   traffic to our server.
>
> Solution:   While we cannot 100%
>   protect the images from inclusion, we
>   can at least restrict the cases where
>   the browser sends a HTTP Referer
>   header.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.quux-corp.de/~quux/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.gif$        -                                    [F]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}         !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}         !.*/foo-with-gif\.html$
RewriteRule ^inlined-in-foo\.gif$   -                        [F]
```

Comment: Great example. There's no 100% solution, but this comes as close as it gets, as the referer header is not mandatory and would be easy to tweak, though not in situations mentioned in the question. +1